# My buttons aren't being placed on the bottom in my App, irregardless of my layout or constraints

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, button, kotlin

I'm trying to have my two buttons, Add and Delete, show up on the bottom of the screen within this particular fragment. Now, I will later use this fragment alongside another to display them side by side, but that's a later problem and I hope that what I solve from here will not cause issues later down the road

I'm using constraintLayout's layout_Constraint to try to place them at the bottom. I previously used FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, and LinearLayout to handle this, to no avail. Is there anything else any of you could recommend?

activity_main.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.contactslist.main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".main">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Delete"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >
</Button>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my Design Tab, it shows up correctly, with the buttons on the bottom. But not in my actual app, where it shows them on the top, albeit still oriented to the right or left, as they should be. Any and all help would be appreciated

EDIT: I believe I may have fixed the problem with the use of match_parent in my fragment.xml file and sticking with ConstrainLayout. But, I wonder, will that 'cause me problems down the road, such as for when I need to place two fragments side by side or need to transfer information between fragments? I'm honestly not sure how to handle the later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this linear layout for the fragment. This fits itself on any screen as I have used weights. I usually do not like Consraint Layout as its gets complicated to use all the  constraints for a responsive layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#202020"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contact_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
  />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Add"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's honestly pretty helpful, albeit, for when I want to switch to landscape mode and have two fragments displayed side by side, wouldn't the linear layout cause me issues there?

Comment: @CodingPoding Well that can cause problems. But won't it better to Create a Landscape Variiation xml if its just two fragments and put the above and the other layout in landscape variation side by side. You can apply weights to both Layout widths in Landscape variation.  .

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my plan. To have a vertical xml and a landscape variation xml to handle that. I can't deny that Constraint Layout makes it more annoying to have to use constraints for everything to be laid out

Comment: In the landscape variation, put the fragments inside a grid layout with rows:1,cols:2. Then apply row weight and col weight 1 to the two fragments inside.

Comment: Oh alright, well that makes sense. Thank you. Erm...I have another question, if you don't mind me asking. For my functions, should I have them handled in the fragment.kt file or in the MainActivity.kt file? Only asking because I didn't add anything to my fragment.kt file and just kept everything in my MainActivity.kt file. I'm trying to use ArrayAdapter and it's 'causing my app to crash and I can't help but feel that it may have to do with how I'm using my fragment and activities

Comment: I think, its better to keep the functions where they belong.Like the click listener functions for the above buttons should be placed in the relevant fragment class. 
I don't know why its crashing. Maybe you are not setting the adapter in the fragment's class and make sure your ArrayAdapter is initialized like this:
ListView myList;
myList=findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
ArrayAdapter myAdapter= new 
ArrayAdapter(YourFragmentClass.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,YourDataArray);
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: Oh so you'd recommend I move my functions to my fragment class? I just kept everything in my MainActivity class and didn't add anything to my fragment class

Comment: Yes that is the normal way of doing it, keeping the objects in the particular domain. I hope you know how to inflate fragments.

Comment: Ahh...so then I shouldn't have an issue with moving my functions from the activity kotlin file to the fragment kotlin then. I suppose I'd need to just have the activity kotlin file call upon my fragment in that case. On how to inflate fragments, I honestly wouldn't know much

Comment: Yes. Like the click listeners can be easily placed inside the fragment class. And the ArrayAdapter also because they belong there, if not then why creating a separate fragment class. I use java but both kotlin and java use the same logic except syntax.

Comment: Well I have a friend who's just keeping his fragments as they are from when they were created and just putting all of his functions and what have you within his activity files and it seems to be getting the job done for him. I'll try what you're doing. Of course, I suppose I should ask if the inputted data, like the contact name, phone number, etc. will be saved, even if I use a fragment

Comment: Well it depends on how you handle the data using your logic. Like for the ArrayAdapter, you can decide from where to put the data in the list. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see. Well that's very helpful, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So, you used wrap_content as your size for the fragment. That only makes the item as large as it needs to be to fit all the elements in (and, essentially, as small as possible otherwise). When you changed that to match_parent, the fragment stretched to fit the parent (which is, in this instance, the entire safe area). It will cause you issues when you add additional fragments only if you don't change this. You can set it up to share space equally with other fragments if necessary; or put all the fragments in a scroll view if you don't have enough room for all of them. Either way, you'll remove match_parent later.

Comment: Oh alright. Well how would you recommend I have the two fragments share the space equally, side by side? Should I have the widths = wrap_content and the rest match parent?

Comment: This is actually pretty simple. There are a few ways to do it. Let's talk only single axis, here. We'll go with horizontal and we'll imagine that your fragments should both match the height of the parent. The way I do it is to set fragment 1 and 2 height to match_parent, set fragment1 and fragment2 width to 0dp (seems odd, but it's made to work this way), and then fragment1.layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" and fragment1.layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fragment2". Then, fragment2.layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fragment1" and fragment2.layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"

Comment: If that's all, select a correct answer or what have you!